# Will I have enough time to make 1 hour connection in LAX to PVR?

Tags: layovers, short-connections, lax, delta-air-lines

We're flying Delta from Minneapolis to Puerto Vallarta.  We have 1 hour stop in LAX, is that enough time to make our flight to PVR?

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket? Do you have checked luggage?

Comment: same ticket, yes we will have checked luggage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's booked on a single ticket and your inbound flight is on time, you should be ok.

Today the MSP flight came into terminal three and the PVR flight left from terminal 2. The terminals are connected airside, but you have to take the Delta shuttle bus.

See https://renespoints.boardingarea.com/2019/05/31/delta-lax-shuttle-bus-moves-gates-terminal-2-where-now-find-it/